# Calculating probability related to a random variable and its transformation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, transformation

**Question**

Let $Y = \sqrt X$, where $X$ has cumulative distribution function

$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases}
0\qquad \mathrm{if}\ x < 0,\\
\frac 1 8 x^3\quad \mathrm{if}\ 0 \leq x \leq 2,\\
1\qquad \mathrm{if}\ x > 2.\\
\end{cases}$$

Find $\mathbb{P}[Y \leq X]$.

**My working**

$$\begin{aligned}
f_Y(y) & = f_X(x) \frac {\mathrm{d}x} {\mathrm{d}y}\\
& = \frac 3 8 x^2 (2y)\\
& = \frac 3 4 y^5\ \forall\ y \in [0, \sqrt 2]
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
\implies \mathbb{P}[Y \leq X] & = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^x_{-\infty} f_X(x)f_Y(y)\ \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x\\
& = \int^2_0 \int^x_0 \left(\frac 3 8 x^2\right)\left(\frac 3 4 y^5\right)\ \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x\\
& = \int^2_0 \frac 3 {64} x^8\ \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x\\
& = \frac 8 3
\end{aligned}$$

However, this is clearly incorrect as my probability is greater than $1$, but I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most clear mistake is that $X$ and $Y$ are not indepenedent! So you can't compute the density $f_{X,Y}$ as $f_Xf_Y$.

One way to get a correct answer is note that $Y \leq X$ if and only if $\sqrt{X} \leq X$, i.e. if and only if $\sqrt{X}(\sqrt{X}-1) \geq 0$. (This uses that $X$ and $Y$ are positive.) This inequality holds if $\sqrt{X}=0$ or if $\sqrt{X}\geq 1$, so you just have to compute these two probabilites. The first one gives us $\mathbb{P}[X=0]=0$ as $X$ is continuous, and the second one yields
$$ \mathbb{P}[X\geq 1] = 1-\mathbb{P}[X \leq 1] = 1-F_X(1) = 1 -\frac{1}{8}=\frac{7}{8}. $$
(This uses again that $X$ is continuous, so that $\mathbb{P}[X\leq 1]=\mathbb{P}[X=1]$.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Going by this logic, if I wanted to find $\mathbb{P}\left(X \leq \frac 1 2 Y\right)$, would that be equivalent to $\mathbb{P}\left(X < \frac 1 4\right)$?

Comment: In this case yes! But note that you are using that $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables to discard $X=1/4$ and $X=0$. This is not relevant here, but is important to keep in mind.

Comment: I see. And just to make sure I am really getting this right, say I wanted to find $\mathbb{P}\left(X + Y \leq \frac 3 4\right)$. I manipulated it to become $\mathbb{P}\left[\sqrt X(\sqrt X + 1) \leq \frac 3 4\right]$ and I note that $\sqrt X + 1$ is always greater than $\frac 3 4$, so does this mean $\mathbb{P}\left(X + Y \leq \frac 3 4\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\sqrt X \leq \frac 3 4\right)$?

Comment: Hmmmmm no, I don't think so, but this is just an algebraic problem. It is true that $\mathbb{P}[X+Y \leq \frac{3}{4}]$ is the same as $\mathbb{P}[\sqrt{X}(\sqrt{X}+1) \leq \frac{3}{4}]$. However, this holds when $s \leq \frac{1}{2}$. (For instance, write it as $4s^2+4s \leq 3$ for $s=\sqrt{X}$, and try factoring it.)

Comment: Oh right! The factorisation indeed does the trick! So $\mathbb{P}\left(X + Y \leq \frac 3 4\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\sqrt X \leq \frac 1 2\right)$ in this case? Since the inequality would not be true elsewhere!

Answer (score 2):

You are requesting to calulate

$$P(\sqrt{X}-X<0)$$

that is

$$P(X>1)=1-F(1)=\frac{7}{8}$$

Answer (score 2):

We have $Y = \sqrt X$, and hence $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

We are to find $P(\sqrt X \leq X), 0 \leq x \leq 2$ and we know that $\sqrt x \leq x$ when $x \geq 1$.

So, $\displaystyle P(Y \leq X) = P(X \geq 1) = 1- P(X \lt 1) = \frac{7}{8}$